# About how the alternative is selected on variant construction with a single argument?

Tags: c++, initialization, language-lawyer, variant

While reading the standard for the definition of the constructor [[variant.ctor]](http://eel.is/c++draft/variant.ctor):

```
template<class T> constexpr variant(T&& t) noexcept(see below);
```

I fall on an obscure limitation:

> Let `Tj` be a type that is determined as follows: build an imaginary function `FUN(Ti)` for each alternative type `Ti` for which 
>   `Ti x[] = {std​::​forward<T>(t)}`; is well-formed for some invented variable `x` ...he overload `FUN(Tj)` selected by overload resolution for the expression `FUN(std​::​forward<T>(​t))` defines the alternative `Tj` which is the type of the contained value after construction.

I would like to understand what is the intent behind **this limitation**:

> for which `Ti x[] = {std​::​forward<T>(t)};` *is well-formed*?

Without this restriction, overload resolution would have eliminated all overloads for which the parameter can not be initialized by copy initinialization.

As far as I have dug, `Ti x[] = {std::forward<T>(t)}` should fall on [[dcl.init.aggr]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#aggr-4.2):

> Otherwise, the element is copy-initialized from the corresponding initializer-clause or is initialized with the brace-or-equal-initializer of the corresponding designated-initializer-clause. If that initializer is of the form assignment-expression or = assignment-expression *and a narrowing conversion ([dcl.init.list]) is required to convert the expression, the program is ill-formed*.

So I see this limitation remove from the set of overloaded imaginary functions those that would involve a narrowing conversion when called. But maybe there is more? Am I wrong? Why an array initialization in the limitation, why not `Ti x = {std::forward<T>(t)}`? What is the intent behind "`Ti x[] = {std​::​forward<T>(t)};` is well-formed"?

Comment: Well for one thing, if it were `Ti x = {std::forward<T>(t)}` then it would allow initializer list constructors even when an initialzer list was not the argument. By making it an array it never allows that case. But I have no idea if that's actually a contributing factor for the decision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wording is added by [P0608R3 A sane variant converting constructor](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0608r3.html). The paper summarizes the change very well in the [Proposed resolution](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0608r3.html#Proposed-resolution) section:

> This paper proposes to constrain the `variant` converting constructor
>   and the converting assignment operator to prevent narrowing
>   conversions and conversions to `bool`. This section explains what
>   exactly this change brings.

Therefore, the only intent of this change is to prevent narrowing conversions.

Why is an array used?  A drafting note in the [Wording](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0608r3.html#Wording) section answers your question:

> *[ Drafting note:* The above uses `T`<sub>*i*</sub> `x[] = {std::forward<T>(t)};` rather than
>   `T`<sub>*i*</sub> `{std::forward<T>(t)}` to test whether the
>   conversion sequence from `T` to `T`<sub>*i*</sub> contains a narrowing
>   conversion because whether
>   `T`<sub>*i*</sub> `{std::forward<T>(t)}` is well-formed may
>   subject to whether `T`<sub>*i*</sub> has an `initializer_list`
>   constructor or whether `T`<sub>*i*</sub> is an aggregate. Here is an
>   example: https://godbolt.org/z/Ck5w-L *– end note ]*